NextJS router push doesn't update the url
I have a bizarre situation where the route push is not working on some query parameters but it does in others.
It's a pure client page component that contains some search parameters and displays a paginated sorted table with data. Whenever a search parameter, page, or sort changes I rebuild the URL to reflect the state, and that triggers rerender and a new call to the API.
It all works fine except for the page query parameter which doesn't trigger any change, but when any other query parameter changes it renders properly in the URL.
This is the snippet where the router updates the URL:
const query = createURLSearchQueryString(...);
const newURL = `${pathname}?${query}`;
console.log("routing ", newURL);
router.push(newURL);

So I can see the new URL is formed correctly, and in these examples, it works fine (does a full rerender and gets the new values from the URL):

sorting: routing /manage/library?page=1&sort=title%7Cdesc
search term: routing /manage/library?s=cat&page=1&sort=title%7Casc
category: routing /manage/library?s=cat&sort=title%7Casc&category%3AGenre%5B%5D=Action+%26+Adventure&page=1

But whenever I try to change the page parameter, the following URL is generated:
routing /manage/library?page=2&sort=title%7Casc

the URL is not updated and none of the values are updated, but the browser scrolls up, like a normal redirect).
For reference, here are some tech details:

Nextjs 14.2.5
App router
Using the useReact hook from next/navigation
All client-side (no SCP involved)

Is there any way to force the router to make a reload? Am I missing something?

The method that performs the database query must be in page.tsx. At the end of the function that obtains the new search there must be the revalidatepath('/post')
In case the search redirects to another page with the search selected, use the redirect('path')
import {redirect} from 'next/navigation'

Also if you are building an API. And you need dynamic data, that is, always fresh data. you must put export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"

As I mentioned in the question there is no server involved, is a purely client issue

use router.refresh()

the url is not updated so the refresh does nothing :(

you must put export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' in page.tsx
